# Casting to unbound generics in Java

Tags: java, spring, casting

I've got the following java pseudocode

```
public interface JobData {}
public class JobStatus<T extends JobData> {
   public T jobData;
}
public class A implements JobData {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends A {}

public class Service {

    private Map<Long, JobStatus> jobStatusMap;

    public <T extends JobData> List <JobStatus<T>> getJobsByJobDataType(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        return jobStatusMap.values().stream()
          .filter(js -> clazz.isInstance(js.getJobData()))
          .map((js) -> (JobStatus<T>) js) // HERE
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble with the line marked "HERE". Essentially, I've got an map of `JobStatus` objects, each of which has a field, `jobData`, which is a generic implementing the interface `JobData`. I want to get all the `JobStatus` items whose `jobData` field is a subclass of class of say, class `A`:

```
List<JobStatus<A>> jobStatuses = getJobsByJobDataType(A.class);
```

How do I, I guess at compile-time, cast my `JobStatus` objects to `JobStatus<T>`?

I can do a dynamic cast in a number of ways via things like `myClass.cast(js)`, but I'm not sure how to do that if `myClass` is a generic `JobStatus<T>` where `T` is bound or alternatively defined in `clazz`.

Comment: What is `JobStatus`? --- Why show us `JobResult` when you never use it? --- `js` is a `JobStatus`, and a `JobStatus` is not a `JobData`, so why did you think the cast  `(JobData<T>) js` would work? --- Since `js` is a `JobStatus`, and return type is a `List <JobStatus<T>>`, why are you even trying to cast anything? --- If `JobStatus` is a generic, i.e. a `JobStatus<T>`, then `Map<Long, JobStatus>` is using a raw generic, and you shouldn't do that. Use `Map<Long, JobStatus<?>>` instead.

Comment: Since you *are* using a raw generic, simply remove the `map(...)` call and everything is fine. --- Though you might need to add `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to the `jobStatusMap` field for a warning-free compilation.

Comment: The filter call can be simplified to `.filter(js -> clazz.isInstance(js.getJobData()))`

Comment: Sorry, having trouble keeping track of the names. I think i've fixed them now. The raw generic is because I'm refactoring existing code and just trying this out. The goal of this question is to see if I can return the specific `JobStatus<C>` class. I can do it without it fine.

Comment: Why are you using `clz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())` instead of `clz.isInstance(obj)`? The latter is straight to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're attempting to cast elements to a type that is different from the list type.  In other words, your return signature is of type `List<JobStatus<T>>` where `JobStatus` does not extend `JobData`, although you're trying to cast each assignable element to the type `JobData`.

Is this what you want to do?

```
public interface JobData<T> {
    T getData();
}

public interface JobStatus<T extends JobData> {
    T getJobData();
}

public class Service {

    private Map<Long, JobStatus> jobStatusMap;

    public <T extends JobData> List<JobStatus<T>> getJobsByJobDataType(Class<T> clazz) {
        return jobStatusMap.values().stream()
                .filter(value -> clazz.isAssignableFrom(value.getJobData().getClass()))
                .map(value -> (JobStatus<T>) value)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and @andreas. It seems I I confused the classes and that was the problem.